# dechex function outputs wrong result

Tags: php, linux, 64-bit, php-7

I have a simple problem but fairly complex and I could use some advice on how to solve it.
I've been trying all solutions of questions asked before but none of them seem to work.

```
echo dechex(0.258068 * 1000000000000000000); //returns 394d77a8be54020
```

The correct value however is

> 394D77A8BE54000

how can I convert it to the correct value, I understand is a big integer and that is a problem, but how can I obtain correct values inside my script ?

Comment: Where did you get your "correct value"?

Comment: Your correct value is wrong, the returned value is correct

Comment: `//returns 394d77a8be54020` - I doubt that; I'm getting back `8be54020` which is part of that returned string you say you're getting and feel you've left something out as in what's creating that other prepended string set. You running 32 or 64 bit? It matters.

Comment: @HerryPotei  using qalculate for linux I am getting 394D77A8BE54000 and is the correct value, I am using it in other software

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner running 64 bit linux php 7

Comment: @MehdiBounya if you do the reverse hexdec on 394d77a8be54020 the value will end in 32 number and 0.258068 * 1000000000000000000 defenetly doesn't have 32 in the end

Comment: @stifler77 Well, 0.258068 * 1000000000000000000 = 258,068,000,000,000,030 |

258068000000000030 to Hexadecimal gives: 394D77A8BE54020

Comment: @MehdiBounya it should be only 0 after 68 where does 30 come from in the end

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point I think..

Comment: @MehdiBounya the expected result _is_ correct. You are mistaken.

Comment: @AdamCameron It has to do with the floating point problem right? when I said it was right I just repeated the steps and got the same result.

Comment: @MehdiBounya yeah, you can see the issue in my example below. Not sure how you ended up with 258068000000000030 though? That's not what I got when I multiplied the numbers together (again, as per the example).

Comment: @AdamCameron I used DuckDuckGo. my laptop's calculator shows **2.58068×10¹⁷**

Comment: Which is not `258068000000000030` ;-) Anyway, no harm done. Bottom line: one cannot expect accuracy in float arithmetic when the orders of magnitude between the operands is so disparate (and FP arithmetic is intrinsically in accurate anyhow, as you know).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct: you're getting a floating point inaccuracy error. Note that `0.258068 * 1000000000000000000` is a float, not an integer.

Here's a solution:

```
echo 0.258068 * 1000000000000000000;
echo PHP_EOL;
$i = bcmul(0.258068, 1000000000000000000);
echo $i;
echo PHP_EOL;
$h = dechex($i);
echo $h;
```

Result:

```
2.58068E+17
258068000000000000
394d77a8be54000
```

Refs:

[Live example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9e30027d62d98428c3c67dfdb001498f14dc70c2)

[bcmul](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcmul.php)

Comment: wow thanks a lot man, I've been struggling with this problem for the past 5 hours. thank you x1000

Comment: however for this echo dechex(bcmul(20, 1000000000000000000));  result is also bad

Comment: `dechex` takes and integer, and `20 x 1000000000000000000` overflows an integer. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/33393a13a011dc1a210795f82ea89491df94b827. http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php. What are you actually trying to achieve here? You might need to write yer own arbitrary-length dex2hex converter. That said, what are you needing to do this for in the first place? Why do you need to be converting these large numeric values to hex for?

Comment: Solved it using a dechex from php function docs, thanks. I am using it to interact with the ethereum json rpc.